# what is the difference between 10 <=n<=1 and n<=1 or n>=10?

Tags: python-3.x

Given a number n, return True if n is in the range 1..10, inclusive. Unless outside_mode is True, in which case return True if the number is less or equal to 1, or greater or equal to 10.

```
def in1to10(n, y):
  if y:
    if n<= 1 or n >= 10:
      return True
    else:
      return False
      
  else:
    if n >= 1 and n <= 10:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

I can't understand the difference between the code, please explain codingbat problem

```
def in1to10(n, y):
  if y:
    if 10 <= n <=1:
      return True
    else:
      return False
      
  else:
    if 1<= n <= 10:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

Comment: `10 <= n <=1` means `10 <= n and n <= 1`, which is always false.

Comment: Read about [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). TL;DR - *"Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false)."*

Comment: Replace n with a number and read it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`10 <= n <= 1` basically means `n <= 1 and n >= 10` which is different from `n <= 1 or n >= 10`

Lets put them underneath each other to see the difference:

```
n <= 1 and n >= 10
n <= 1 or  n >= 10
```

As you can see they are identical, except the first one uses logical `and` while the other one uses logical `or`

This means that in the first one both comparisons must end up being true, while in the second one only one of them has to be true

This whole `a <= b <= c` syntax is just syntax sugar named 'comparison chaining' you can read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 def in1to10(n, outside_mode):
  if  outside_mode and( n>=10 or n<=1):
      return True
  elif outside_mode and( n<10 and n>1):
    return False
  else:
    if 1<=n<=10 and outside_mode == False:
        return True
    elif outside_mode == False and n<1 or n>10:
      return False
```